# Will "a" or "the" be presumed in this scenario?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Suppose a native English-speaking witness in court is testifying about what she saw. The story, as previously narrated by the witness in her written statement, starts with a certain identified/named person, known to be a farmer, arriving at a certain place.

So, when asked to tell the story again, verbally, not looking at the previous statement, she starts: "Farmer came along and...".

Does she mean "a farmer" or "the farmer"?

Comment: *So, when asked to tell the story again, verbally, not looking at the previous statement, she starts: "Farmer came along and...* No, she does not. She says "**The** farmer... "

Comment: @Greybeard I am asking about a witness questioning that has factually happened in which she said "Farmer" — without any articles. So I want to know how that should be interpreted — with "a" or "the".

Comment: *I am asking about a witness questioning that has factually happened* - No, you're not: you started with "Suppose" - this implies an unreal scenario. -- As the farmer has been mentioned before, it is "the".

Comment: If she’s a native speaker, it’s more likely that Farmer (without articles) was someone’s surname.

Comment: @Greybeard I start with "Suppose" merely to generalise the question, avoid tying it to real facts. It is simply a _premise_ of the question that the witness does not use any articles, so your claim that she _uses_ "the" is unhelpful.

Comment: @Lawrence She had previously identified his surname in her written statement. If that was "Farmer", I obviously wouldn't even ask this question here.

Comment: This won't get a definitive answer here, and you may want to ask on law.stackexchange.com, which will help with people's experiences. "Farmer" here sounds to me (opinion based) that the witness is referring to the generic placeholder of "farmer". Ask tomorrow and I may disagree with myself. Even if the burden of proof is 50% plus a feather, I'd find it hard to believe you'd get an interpretation either way to sway a judge or jury. Unfortunately, you're reading tea leaves. law.stackexchange.com will be able to provide better context.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think law.stackexchange.com will provide a better framing for the question than we can get in EL&U. Otherwise, it's simply ambiguous or a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "the farmer".

It would be uncommon to see someone use that phrase in testimony (this is just sloppy speech in all likelihood), but in legal writing (e.g. contracts and court filings) it is common to define the term "Farmer" to mean, as a proper noun, the person described initially, and to use that term for the remainder of the document as a proper noun.

One reason this is done is that it allows the writing to prepare a generic form that is descriptive enough to obviously refer to a particular person, in which someone using the form can fill in one blank with the actual name of the person being referred to in this particular filing or contract, without having to make changes throughout the body text.

It is also used this way when the actual proper name of the person in question is not known, or when the actual proper name of the person in question is long or hard to pronounce (or has negative ethnic connotations that one fears could cause the court to act with implicit prejudice).

In court filings, this is sometimes done when there are many people with names that could be easily confused by a reader in the discussion easier to read, by emphasizing the role that someone plays in the legal dispute in a way that is relevant to the court reading it, rather than their particular name.

So, for example, rather than referring to John Smith who gets legal services from Jim Beam, the document might define "John Smith" when first used in the document as "Client" and "Jim Beam" when first used in the document as "Attorney". This way, a reader who forgot the names of the parties from the initial description of facts can jump into reading the document in the middle and properly analyze the legal rights of the parties and easily compare them to similar cases where people have those roles.